# Cant make pretty sybolic math output using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
x = symbols('x')

my_ex = x**2
print(my_ex)
```

Output:

```
x**2
```

Hoped for a nice symbolic output, what am i doing wrong?

Was hoping for an outcome like the one below:

[image]

Comment: Please specify what are you expecting to get.

Comment: Hi Alex, i have tried to attach an image of the expected output

Comment: `print(my_ex)` gives you content of my_ex variable, when to see symbolic form just call your variable like `my_ex`. See [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N20F3-p33wa9zmQbwpqzhXk4rqRx_T7O?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jupyter's `display`, so

```
display(my_ex)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you :D

Comment: What is the difference between `my_ex` and `display(my_ex)`?

Comment: Just `my_ex` will only generate output if it occurs on the last line of a cell. If you want to display several expressions, or if you do not necessarily want to write the thing you want to display on the last line, then you need `display(my_ex)`. This is, by the way, a generic thing in Jupyter (also holds true for `print`).